# zend framework using mysql_real_escape_string in 2 tier server

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, mysql-real-escape-string

In one of my application I'm using zend framework. web/application server, database server are physically different. now i'm using `mysql_real_escape_string` for security where i am giving first parameter. and it gives me an warning "link_identifier not found or no database connection identifier".

when i created a connection identifier for that instance and provided it stared working. my question is why it is not identifying it on its own.

Answer (score 1):

By default, all methods in `Zend_Db_Adapter` will escape your input. So `mysql_real_escape_string` is superfluous

Comment: Escaping is very confusing in zend, they are not clear about when things are escaped or not.